# How to render all html pages in express.js by one app.listen in index.js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want to render all HTML pages in my project directory in express.js without writing app.listen for all pages.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you were attempting to do this with app.listen, but you should be using a view template engine. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Ok, I started using ejs! But it still needs a res.render for each ejs file to render! I want it to be like I have to write only one code for rendering all ejs files in my folder! How can I achieve that? @knicholas

Comment: is there a reason why you would want render ALL of your ejs at once? Maybe I would be able to suggest an alternative if I knew the purpose for doing this...

Comment: i am making a chat application! So there will be new pages made all the time! So I need to render all! Or else I cant just add res.render for all groups, right? So I do need another way round

Comment: And I dont want to render all pages at once! I will have links(<a>) tags in my ejs so I need to type res.render for all pages! That is the problem @knicholas

Comment: Oh I see. You would have to use res.render for each route your user would be navigating to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer for this. It was quite a struggle but I got:-

```
// Variables
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'app')))

// Start Server
server.listen(PORT,() => console.log(`Server Running at ` + PORT))
```

This is the code. Thanks for your help!
And I used socket.io too.